# Run multiple terminal commands using Swift

Tags: swift, macos, terminal, fastlane

I want to execute two commands one after the other in macOS Application.
For Example `cd ~/Desktop/MyiOSProject` and 'fastlane releaseBeta'

I have implemented command line execution in below method.
When I invoke bellow method `command("cd ~/Desktop/MyiOSProject && fastlane releaseBeta")` it throws me error

> env: cd ~/Desktop/MyiOSProject && fastlane releaseBeta: No such file
>   or directory

```
func command(args: String..., completion: @escaping (Bool,String, Process)->Void) {
        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
        task.arguments = args
        let outPipe = Pipe()
        task.standardOutput = outPipe
        task.launch()
        task.terminationHandler = {process in
            let outdata = outPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
            if var string = String(data: outdata, encoding: .utf8) {
                string = string.trimmingCharacters(in: .newlines)
                if process.terminationStatus == 0 {
                    completion(true, string, process)
                }else {
                    completion(false, string, process)
                }

                return
            }
            completion(false, "Failed to run command", process)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same issue as you.

Answer (score 1):

Within a `Process` instance, you don’t have the same environment that you have inside Terminal. I. e. search paths are different—although you use `/usr/bin/env`. I suspect that the `fastlane` command cannot be found. If so, the solution ist simple: specify the full path to it, i. e. `/usr/local/bin/fastlane`.